# Automatically selecting dates from databases as Zend_Date objects

Tags: oracle, zend-framework, timestamp, zend-date

From what I understand, the best way to deal with dates in the Zend Framework is to select them as a Unix timestamp from the database.

[Quick Creation of Dates from Database Date Values](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.creation.html#zend.date.creation.database.example-1)

```
// SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_datetime_column) FROM my_table
$date = new Zend_Date($unixtimestamp, Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
```

I think it's a pain that there is actually no easy way in Oracle to either select dates as Unix timestamps or in ISO-8601 format - which are the two formats `Zend_Date` knows best.

But I did write a function to select dates as unix timestamps in PL/SQL, so I can actually do this now.

Using `Zend_Db_Expr`, I can now select my dates as Unix timestamps:

```
$select = $db->select()
             ->from(array('p' => 'products'),
                    array(
                        'product_id',
                        'product_date' => new Zend_Db_Expr('toUnixTimestamp(product_date)')
                    )
               );

$results = $db->fetchAll($select);
```

You would use a similar query for any RDMS - most have a timestamp function.

I find this anoying because now I have to loop through $results to transform the timestamp to a Zend_Date object manually:

```
foreach($results as $result){
    $productDate = new Zend_Date($result['product_date'], Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
    echo $productDate->toString('dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
}
```

I want my Model to return $results where the timestamps are already transformed to Zend_Date. I don't want to have to write a loop in every data-access function to do this for me.

So to get to the point of my actual question:

***Does anyone know of a way with Zend_Db, to set up some sort of post-processing on the result set, thus converting the timestamps to Zend_Date objects automatically?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've encountered scenarios where I've wanted to do this.  Here is the solution that I've used:

- Created an extended row class for Zend_Db_Table_Row and overloaded the __get() and __set() super-methods
- In the specific classes/tables that I want to use date objects, created the appropriate methods to do the heavy lifting

Here is a dumbed-down version of the extended row class that I use on my projects:

```
/**
 * @category   FireUp
 * @package    FireUp_Db
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Fire Up Media, Inc. (http://www.fireup.net)
 * @license    http://dev.fireup.net/license/mit     MIT License
 * @uses       Zend_Db_Table_Row
 */
class FireUp_Db_Table_Row extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Retrieve row field value
     *
     * Checks for the existence of a special method to apply additional handling for the field data and calls the method if it exists
     *
     * @param  string $columnName The user-specified column name.
     * @return string             The corresponding column value.
     * @throws Zend_Db_Table_Row_Exception if the $columnName is not a column in the row.
     */
    public function __get($key)
    {
        $inflector = new Zend_Filter_Word_UnderscoreToCamelCase();

        $method = '_get' . $inflector->filter($key);

        if (method_exists($this, $method))
        {
            return $this->{$method}();
        }

        return parent::__get($key);
    }

    /**
     * Set row field value
     *
     * Checks for the existence of a special method to apply additional handling for the field data and calls the method if it exists
     *
     * @param  string $columnName The column key.
     * @param  mixed  $value      The value for the property.
     * @return void
     * @throws Zend_Db_Table_Row_Exception
     */
    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $inflector = new Zend_Filter_Word_UnderscoreToCamelCase();

        $method = '_set' . $inflector->filter($key);

        if (method_exists($this, $method))
        {
            return $this->{$method}($value);
        }

        return parent::__set($key, $value);
    }
}
```

For our individual table classes, we override the functions as such:

```
class EntityRecord extends FireUp_Db_Table_Row
{
    protected function _getDateCreated()
    {
        return new Zend_Date($this->_data['date_created'], Zend_Date::ISO_8601);
    }

    protected function _setDateCreated($value)
    {
        if ($value instanceof Zend_Date)
        {
            $value = $value->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
        }

        $this->_data['date_created'] = $value;
        $this->_modifiedFields['date_created'] = true;
    }
}
```

Now, creating a new Zend_Date object everytime that the field would be accessed has some overhead, so in our classes, we take additional measures to cache the date objects, etc, but I didn't want that to get in the way of showing you the solution.

Comment: This assumes that you are using Zend_Db_Table and specifying the row class for the model

Comment: I would do it the same way. You can do the same thing in any other persistence layer other the nZend_Db_Table ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use Zend_Table and have your table return you custom row objects that [extend `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.row.html#zend.db.table.row.extending).  Then just have a method on that row like

```
function getDate() {
    return new Zend_Date($this->datecol, Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
}
```